# Как лучше будет создать интернет магазин?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как лучше будет создать интернет магазин?
Лучше будет использовать CMS платформы, или же создать на html, css, js?
И можно ли использовать CMS как backend, а frontend сделать самому?

Comment: возьмите bitrix и радуйтесь ..а вообще вопрос вне тематики ресурса

Comment: для рекомендующих битрикс в аду есть отдельный котел.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь скажи что ocstore или woocomerce или modx или может webasyst лучше ?

Comment: Учитывая сколько надо заплатить за сам битрикс + каждый месяц за сервер платить несколько к, который будет тянуть это де*******мо еле еле, да лучше. например все что выше перечислено и еще virtuemart

Comment: @MaximLensky Учитывая это https://www.govnokod.ru/221 ДА! ЛУЧШЕ!

Comment: @MaximLensky а я бы порекомендовал не смотреть рейтинг а думать головой, вернее мозгами.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь а есть альтернативы лучше ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если знаний, для самостоятельной реализации не достаточно, то безусловно советую Вам использовать CMS платформы.
 В них гораздо проще реализовать своей проект, а так же будете иметь возможность не только собирать статистику, но и использовать уже интегрированные инструменты.
На движке по умолчанию доступно большое количество маркетинговых инструментов. В их числе:
 - Аналитические данные, демонстрирующие портрет аудитории и показывающие посещаемость. (Вместо аналитики гугл и яндекса.
 - Система рассылки уведомлений зарегистрированным пользователям.
 - Размещение сайта на VPS и тех. поддержка.
 - Виджеты для общения с клиентами на сайте и за его пределами.
 - Инструменты SEO.
 - Возможность быстро сделать сайт при помощи шаблонов.
 - Авторизация через соцсети и соцбар для расшаривания ссылок.
 - A/B-тестирование для исследования эффективности торгового предложения.
 - плюс возможность использовать шаблоны интерфейса и его частей.

Так же не стоит забывать, что Вам придётся со временем добавлять товары на сайт и вносить изменения. CMS системы предоставляют простую и понятную форму администрирования сайта.

**НО**

Всё это можно реализовать и своими руками, если не хотите переплачивать, или Вас не устраивает ограниченность доступа визуального редактора. 
 Это потребует у Вас большего времени на разработку, а так же все функции сайта, будь-то чат с клиентом, отправка писем, регистрация через соц сети и так далее, Вам придётся реализовывать самостоятельно.
Однако это не так страшно, как может сначала показаться.

На текущий момент существует много фреймворков практически для любого языка программирования. Они очень значительно помогают в реализации практически всех перечисленных нюансов. 
Ну и дополнительно, может понадобится создание простенькой панели администратора для добавления товаров на сайт. (Обычно это сразу учитывается при создании проекта)
 Зато Ваш сайт и его обслуживание будет обходится Вам **гораздо** дешевле, чем пользование любой CMS платформой. 
 А так же Вы сможете реализовать все свои идеи в плане оформления.

На первый взгляд, самостоятельное создание сайта может показаться очень сложной идеей, однако, это всё гораздо проще, чем кажется. Любой толковый программист без труда сможет реализовать подобный проект за неделю-две. (Всё сильно зависит от "хотелок" ) =)